# Why is the BranchId filtered in the data view SQL statement

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I create a custom DAC, which contains a BranchID field.  The client's requirements for this field, is to insert the value 0, as default.  The field is defined as a KeyField, but no PXDefault attribute is defined.  I use PXRowPersisting event handler, in order to set the value in cases of 0.  I use a ListView screen, in order to return the records.  But no records are returned.  I noticed in the SQL trace, that a filter is applied to BranchID field:
`AND ([MyCustomTable].BranchID IS NULL OR [MyCustomTable].BranchID IN (16, 17, 20))` 
Why is this filter added?

Comment: But did you use the Branch attribute in your BranchID field ?

Comment: I removed the selector entirely.  The but where clause is still added
[PXDBInt(IsKey =true)]  
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Building ID")]   
public virtual int? BranchID { get; set; }
public abstract class branchID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

Comment: That is interesting. Could be something in the framework looking for the standard name of "BranchID". What happens if you change the name of the field to something different (Ex: "MyBranchID"). This would confirm the framework matching by name and might be your best bet to get around the issue you described. Why it occurs I don't know but it would make sense maybe based on user rights to branch access?

Answer (score 0):

For any table, that contains **BranchID** or **UsrBranchID** column, the framework automatically includes the **BranchID** condition into **Where** clauses. No matter what attributes are applied on a DAC field, if partucular DAC is bound to the table containing **BranchID** or **UsrBranchID** column, the **BranchID** condition will be added into all **Where** clauses generated for this table.

For your specific scenario, a possible solution would be to rename **BranchID** column to something different than **BranchID** or **UsrBranchID**. If you will ever need to force application of the Branch-based access restriction to your custom DAC, just add the `MatchWithBranch<MyDAC.myBranchID>` operator into a BQL query.

Comment: Automatic BranchID condition can be turned off by using PXReadBranchRestrictedScope with no parameters